# Angular JS 1.5.X shows errors with controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I am writing a simple controller example with angular.js version 1.5.X which has some issues worth noting. The problem is only encountered with Angular JS version 1.5.X but I have tested the code with Angular JS V 1.2.X which works as expected. I am not sure if I am  doing something in an outdated fashion ? I am unable to understand the console logs.

My Code-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Angular Demo</title>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller = "MyController">
  <h1>{{author.name}}</h1>
  <p>{{ author.title + ', ' + author.company }}</p>
</div>

<script>
function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.author = {
    'name' : 'Ray Villalobos',
    'title' : 'Staff Author',
    'company' : 'Lynda.com'
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

{{author.name}}

{{ author.title + ', ' + author.company }}

Console Log:

```
angular.min.1.5.X.js:118 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ng/areq?p0=MyController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:6:412
    at sb (file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:23:18)
    at Pa (file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:23:105)
    at file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:89:310
    at ag (file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:72:419)
    at p (file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:64:262)
    at g (file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:58:481)
    at g (file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:58:498)
    at g (file:///G:/Programming-Joy/Web/JavaScript/JavaScript%20Essential%20Training%20Lynda/AngularJs/lib/angular/angular.min.1.5.X.js:58:498)
```

Comment: Core issue was explained in marked duplicate answer, other part of the issue is you have to host your application on server so that file will get access over `http` protocol. Currently they seems to be talking about `file` protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Angular above 1.3 you need to defined controller like this,

```
 app.controller("MyController" , function($scope)
   {
       $scope.author = {
      'name' : 'Ray Villalobos',
      'title' : 'Staff Author',
      'company' : 'Lynda.com'
      }
   });
```

[`DEMO APP`](https://plnkr.co/edit/D1pachLSkDTkNGxAHdbu?p=preview)